# Error "database error write ‘Invalid default value for" while installing wordpress site using duplicator plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have export one of my wordpress website using duplicator plugin. Now when trying to setup it on my localhost, it is not able to able to import few tables in database. Which cause site not running on localhost.

While check the doplicator plugin log i got a lot errors, few are:

```
**********************************************************************
```

VERSION: 1.1.0
PHP: 7.0.2 | SAPI: apache2handler
SERVER: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/7.0.2

---

---

DATABASE-ROUTINES

---

————————————–
SERVER ENVIROMENT
————————————–
MYSQL VERSION: 5.7.9
TIMEOUT: 5000
MAXPACK: 1048576
————————————–
DATABASE RESULTS
————————————–

```
**ERROR** database error write ‘Invalid default value for ‘comment_date” – [sql=
CREATE TABLE wp_comments (
comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Invalid default value for ‘created” – [sql=
CREATE TABLE wp_duplicator_packages (
id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NUL…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Invalid default value for ‘link_updated” – [sql=
CREATE TABLE wp_links (
link_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Invalid default value for ‘post_date” – [sql=
CREATE TABLE wp_posts (
ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Invalid default value for ‘user_registered” – [sql=
CREATE TABLE wp_users (
ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME…]
**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_duplicator_packages’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=

/* INSERT TABLE DATA: wp_duplicator_packages */
INSERT INTO `wp_duplicato…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_duplicator_packages’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_duplicator_packages VALUES(“2”, “20151126_naturalexpressio…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_duplicator_packages’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_duplicator_packages VALUES(“3”, “20151126_naturalexpressio…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=
/* INSERT TABLE DATA: wp_posts */
INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“4”, “1”, …]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“5”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:22:39”, “2015-09-07 …]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“7”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:30:51”, “2015-09-07 …]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“8”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:32:08”, “2015-09-07 …]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“9”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:32:36”, “2015-09-07 …]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“10”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:33:05”, “2015-09-07…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“11”, “1”, “2015-09-07 14:34:39”, “2015-09-07…]

**ERROR** database error write ‘Table ‘ne.wp_posts’ doesn’t exist’ – [sql=INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(“19”, “1”, “2015-09-09 08:33:24”, “2015-09-09…]
```

---

I have googled and found that updating sql_mode with NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION will solve the issue.

Since I am using LAMP, i opened /etc/mysql/my.cnf and added the below line:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

and restarted the apache server using below command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But it does not solve the issue. Let me know your solution .... thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just found a solution in wordpress support topics that fixed my problem. The solution is to update the database.sql file in the duplocator package. Here is the steps:

1. open the database.sql in the duplicator archive
2. add the below line at the top on the file.

   SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
3. saved the file and the archive too.
4. Now proceed with your site setup as usual to setup a duplicator package :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, this helped me too. But it would be even more helpful if you gave us the link to the WP Support Topic where you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by adding: sql-mode="" in my.ini file in the \bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14 folder. (on WAMP - so I guess it's something similar on LAMP)